# A Symbol with Subscript and Superscript as an Axis Label

Tags: formatting, fonts, labeling

I am trying to have the symbol $\epsilon_{9/2,4}^-$ as the axis label in a graph in Mathematica. First problem is that: when I use Subscript[$\epsilon$,9/2,4], 9/2 changes to $\frac{9}{2}$ (which I don't want, because it doesn't look good). Second problem is that Subscript[$\epsilon$,9/2,4]^- does not work. Can anyone please let me know how to do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: OK, I found the answer. This works Subscript[ϵ,"9/2",4]^"-". So, please ignore this question.

Comment: maybe you want to look at `Subsuperscript[\[Epsilon], "9/2,4", "-"]`

Comment: "OK, I found the answer." - please write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

One very robust way to do such things is using the BoxLanguage of Mma. Your task for example is solved by the construct:

```
SubsuperscriptBox["\[Epsilon]", "2.4", "-"] // DisplayForm
```

placed just where you enter the desired AxesLabel. It can be, however, styled in addition, for example, as follows:

```
    StyleBox[SubsuperscriptBox["\[Epsilon]", "2.4", "-"], 
  FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Bold] // DisplayForm
```

I will give below the example of its use for formatting the axes labels, by fromatting them differently (e.g. different colors, fonts and fixing FontWeight):

```
    Plot[Sin[eps], {eps, 0, 3}, 
 AxesLabel -> {StyleBox[SubsuperscriptBox["\[Epsilon]", "2.4", "-"], 
     FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Bold] // 
    DisplayForm, 
   StyleBox[SuperscriptBox["x", "y/z"], FontFamily -> "Mathematica6", 
     FontSize -> 18, FontColor -> Blue, FontWeight -> Bold] // 
    DisplayForm}]
```

This returns the following plot: 
[image]

I organized these constructs in such a way that one may use them without knowing anything else about the BoxLanguage.
Have fun!

Comment: Comment just to clarify: The fonts actually looks great unlike in the included image. I guess it looks low resolution here either because of the way it was exported or because it was created using a much older version.

Comment: @Kvothe First, this has been posted in 2014. That is, a rather old version. Second, one has to understand what this image is for. If it rests in a notebook, it will look much better without further effort. If I need to publish a plot, say, in a journal, I use the following trick: `Rasterize[plot, RasterSize->800] ` and play with the value of the `RasterSize` until the quality becomes good enough.

Comment: thanks, and it was not meant as a criticism. I almost dismissed the answer without paying much attention to it because I thought the result was bad anyway. Then I realized that might just be an issue with the included image and tested it. I wanted to warn people that the image looks good so that they don't instantly dismiss the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to provide this with a complete answer, since I had this very same question. There are two ways to enter both a sub and a superscript, one using the `Subsuperscript` command (as noted by @Pinguin Dirk), and one using shortcut keys, which is described in the help:

> To enter a subsuperscript in a notebook, use either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> to begin a
>   regular subscript or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> to begin a regular superscript. After
>   typing the first script, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> to move to the opposite script
>   position. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> moves out of the subscript or superscript
>   position.

Using the shortcut keys enables one to actually have the subsuperscript style while typing, rather than just as an output.